# Split Dataframe into multiple dataframes based on if row contains string

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split a DataFrame based on if a row contains a certain string "Customer" and all subsequent rows until another row that contains "Customer", i.e.

```
c_name       |   cost   | p_date
Customer: xx |          | 
hat          |    12    |   1/1/2018
bat          |    13    |   2/3/2018
Customer: xy |          |
mat          |    14    |   1/2/2018
```

to
     DF1

```
c_name       |   cost   | p_date
Customer: xx |          | 
hat          |    12    |   1/1/2018
bat          |    13    |   2/3/2018
```

DF2

```
c_name       |   cost   | p_date
Customer: xy |          |
mat          |    14    |   1/2/2018
```

I know I can get where to split the DataFrame based on `df.c_name.str.contains('Customer')`, but how do I use that to split the DataFrame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `str.contains` + `groupby`

```
m = df.c_name.str.contains('Customer').cumsum()
d = {f'df{i}': g for i, g in df.groupby(m)}

for k, v in d.items():
    print(k)
    print(v, end='\n\n')
```

```
df1
         c_name  cost    p_date
0  Customer: xx   NaN       NaN
1           hat  12.0  1/1/2018
2           bat  13.0  2/3/2018

df2
         c_name  cost    p_date
3  Customer: xy   NaN       NaN
4           mat  14.0  1/2/2018
```

---

To access the individual DataFrames, simply use `d['df1']`, etc...